# Change the style of the 'active' tag on flags, it's too hard to read

Tags: feature-request, flags

This is what it looks like when a tag is active:

> [image]

That 'active' is almost impossible to read unless I lean in close and squint. Luckily I already know what it says because it appears on other sites where it's more legible.

Could the style change to make the tag legible? In the below I've removed its font-size override so it's just a normal text size, and made that text black or white:

> [image: larger black text]
>
> [image: larger white text]

Michael Jackson won't care which one we pick, but I don't think either one is quite there. White isn't very legible since this is bright orange: it's a 2.14:1 color contrast ratio, when WCAG suggests at least 4.5:1. Black is better, but we could improve it better by making the background lighter:

> [image: larger black text, paler background]

So my ultimate suggestion is, can we move from that first style to this last one?

> [image]
> **↓**  **↓**  **↓**  **↓**  **↓**
>
> [image]